# Modal Image in HTML and CSS with Javascript

Tags: html, css, image, modal-dialog

So i want to create my own gallery using html and css with some JS, i am trying to make the image in modal style so it will look fancy, I got the code for making the image in modal from w3school.com i already change the image scr and other things that will connect the image to the modal. I already tried everything i still can't figure what is wrong with it. Thank you in advance for helping me.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: 8vw 200vw 7vw;
  grid-gap: 0em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;

  
}

header,
footer {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}

main {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  
  
}




body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 89em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right:0;
  padding: 0em 0;
  
}

header,
main,
aside,
footer {
  
  display: flex;
  
}
footer {
 background: #eaeaea;
}

.main1 {
 
 
 margin-top: 450px;
 margin-left: 0;
 
}

#body_1 h2 {
 margin-left: 50px;
 font-size: 30px;
 color: black;
 margin-top: 95px;
 margin-bottom:3px;
 font-family: courier new;
 float: left;
 
}
#body_1 h6 {
 margin-left: 10px;
 
 color: blue;
 margin-top: 220px;
 margin-bottom:3px;
 font-family: courier new;
 float: left;
 
}
#body_1 h4 {
 margin-left: 230px;
 font-size: 30px;
 color: black;
 margin-top: 260px;
 margin-bottom:3px;
 position: left;
 float: left;
 
}


.background_wrap {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(19, 13, 6,0.5);
    z-index: -1000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% ;
    overflow:hidden;
    background: url("Pics&Video/laoang6.jpg") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    
    
    
    
   }
   
.background_wrap::before{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
   



.content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 20%;
    z-index: 1000;
    
    
    
    
   }
.sub-content {
 position: fixed;
 width: 1000px;
 height: 120px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 transition: 0.5s;
 
 
 
}
.sub-content.active {
 background-color: rgba(0, 26, 26,0.7);
 width: 100%
 
}

.sub-content.active ul li a {
 background-color: rgba(0, 26, 26,0.7); 
}
   
#list {
    margin-right: 5px;
    position:fixed;
    margin-left: 780px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    
    
    
   }
   
   
   ul {
    margin-top:1px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    color: white;
    margin-right: 0px;
    font-family: calibri;
    font-weight: bold;
    
    
    
    
    
   }
   ul li {
    float: right;
    width: 130px;
    font-family: courier new;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-right: 1px solid #ffffff ;
    border-left: 1px solid #ffffff ;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff ;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-right: 3px; 
    
    
    
   }
   
   ul li a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 2px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-decoration: none;
    
    
    
   }
   ul li a:hover {
    background-color: green;
    font-weight:bolder;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white
    
   }
   ul li ul li {
    display: none;
    font-weight: bolder;
    
    
    
   }
   ul li:hover ul li {
    display:block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    margin-top:1px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    font-weight: bolder;
    
    
   }
   

    h1 {
    font-family: comic sans ms, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: white;
    
    margin-bottom: 6px; 
   }
   h2 {
    font-family: comic sans ms, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 14%;
     
   }
   
   .wrapper {
    position: center;
    width: 750px;
    height: 100px;
    
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top: 150px;
    
    font-size: 17px;
   }

   .image_wrap {
    margin-top:20px;
    
    height: 70px;
    margin-left:55px;
    
    
   }
   .fl_image {
    float: left;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    
   }
   .content h6 {
    font-family: courier new;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: green;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    
    }
    
   .content p {
    font-family: courier new;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    color: #ffffff;
   }
   
   div.gallery {
     margin: 10px;
     border: 0px solid #ccc;
     float: left;
     width: 250px;
     height:250px;
   }

   div.gallery:hover {
     border: 1px solid #777;
   }

   div.gallery img {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
   }

   
   
   .gallery1 {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 320px;
    margin-left: 10px;
   }
   
   div.gallery {
     margin: 10px;
     border: 0px solid #ccc;
     float: left;
     width: 300px;
     height:250px;
   }

   div.gallery:hover {
     border: 1px solid #777;
   }

   div.gallery img {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
   }

   
   
   .gallery2 {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 840px;
    margin-left: 10px;
   }
   
   .text4  {
    margin-left: 360px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 220px;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    position: left;
    float: left;
 
   }
   #myImg {
     border-radius: 5px;
     cursor: pointer;
     transition: 0.3s;
   }

   #myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

   /* The Modal (background) */
   .modal {
     display: none; /* Hidden by default */
     position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
     z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
     padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     width: 100%; /* Full width */
     height: 100%; /* Full height */
     overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
     background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
   }

   /* Modal Content (Image) */
   .modal-content {
     margin: auto;
     display: block;
     width: 80%;
     max-width: 700px;
   }

   /* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
   #caption {
     margin: auto;
     display: block;
     width: 80%;
     max-width: 700px;
     text-align: center;
     color: #ccc;
     padding: 10px 0;
     height: 150px;
   }

   /* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
   .modal-content, #caption { 
     animation-name: zoom;
     animation-duration: 0.6s;
   }

   @keyframes zoom {
     from {transform:scale(0)} 
     to {transform:scale(1)}
   }

   /* The Close Button */
   .close {
     position: absolute;
     top: 15px;
     right: 35px;
     color: #f1f1f1;
     font-size: 40px;
     font-weight: bold;
     transition: 0.3s;
   }

   .close:hover,
   .close:focus {
     color: #bbb;
     text-decoration: none;
     cursor: pointer;
   }

   /* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
   @media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
     .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
     }
   }
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title> Hotels </title>
  <link style="text/css" href="Hotel.css" rel="stylesheet"  >  </link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
     if($(window).scrollTop()){
      $(".sub-content").addClass('active');
     }else{
      $(".sub-content").removeClass('active');
      }
     })
    });
  </script>
  <script
   // Get the modal
   var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

   // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
   var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
   var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
   var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
   img.onclick = function(){
     modal.style.display = "block";
     modalImg.src = this.src;
     captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
   }

   // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
   var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

   // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
   span.onclick = function() { 
     modal.style.display = "none";
}
  </script>
 
 </head>
<body>

 <header>
  <div class="background_wrap"> 
   
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  <div class="sub-content">
  <img class="image_wrap fl_image" src="Pics&Video\picture.png" height="100px" margin-left="5px" alt="Image One"/> 
  
  <div  id="list" >
   <ul>
    <li><a> <i class="fas fa-file-signature"></i>  Contact</a></li>
    <li><a> <i class="fas fa-user"></i> About</a></li>
    <li><a> Destination </i></a>
     
    </li>
    <li><a> Activities <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="Hotel Main.html"> Hotels</a></li>
      <li><a> Restaurants</a></li>
      <li><a> Festival</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <h6>Samar's Tourism</h6>
  </div>
  
  </div>
  
 
  <div class="wrapper">
  <h2>Search all travel deals, in one go</h2>
  <h1> HOTEL </h1>
  </div>
   
   
 </header>
 
 <main class="main1"> 
  <div id="body_1">
    <h2> Calbayog Hotel </h2> <h6> 2 Places </h6>
    <h4> Baypark Hotel </h4>
    
    <div class="gallery1">
   <div class="gallery">
        <img id="myImg" src="Pics&Video/Western Samar/Calbayog/Baypark/calbayog1.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400"  >
      <div id="myModal" class="modal">

        <!-- The Close Button -->
        <span class="close">&times;</span>

        <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
        <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

        <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
        <div id="caption"></div>
      </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
      
     <img id="myImg" src="Pics&Video/Western Samar/Calbayog/Baypark/calbayog2.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
      
    </div>
    <div class="gallery">
        <img id="myImg" src="Pics&Video/Western Samar/Calbayog/Baypark/calbayog3.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400">
      
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
      
     <img src="Pics&Video/Western Samar/Calbayog/Baypark/calbayog4.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
      
    </div>
   </div> 
   <br>
   <div class="text4">
   <h4> Ciriaco Hotel </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery2">
   <div class="gallery">
        <img src="Pics&Video/Western Samar/Calbayog/Ciriaco/ciriaco1.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400">
      
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
      
     <img src="Pics&Video/Western Samar/Calbayog/Ciriaco/ciriaco2.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
      
    </div>
    <div class="gallery">
        <img src="Pics&Video/Western Samar/Calbayog/Ciriaco/ciriaco3.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400">
      
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
      
     <img src="Pics&Video/Western Samar/Calbayog/Ciriaco/ciriaco4.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
      
    </div>
    
   </div> 
   
   </div> 
    
  
  
  
  
  
 </main >

 <footer>
  Footer
 </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

[calbayog1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhHwX.jpg)

Comment: Do you need a Carousel of images or just a pop-up modal with picture?

Answer (score 0):

There it is my quicker version of a pure Javascript and simple gallery. 
You can adapt it easily ! Feel free to ask clarifications !

```js
var gallery = document.getElementById("gallery");
var imgs = gallery.children;

var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
var modal_img = modal.children[0];

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  imgs[i].onclick = function() {
    modal_img.src = this.src;
    modal.classList.add("show");
  }
}

// Close when clicking anywhere on modal not on img
modal.onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target !== this)
    return;
    
  modal.classList.remove("show");
}
```

```css
#gallery img {
  width: 75px;
  
  cursor: pointer;
}

#modal {
  display: none;
  
  text-align: center;
}

#modal.show {
  display: block;
}

#modal img {
  width: 250px;
  
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

#modal:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" />
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/18/17/42/image-1465348_960_720.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="modal"><img src="" /></div>
```